# 7zip context menu appears twice

Tags: kde, 7z

7zips context menu appears twice to me when I right-click to a file.. Same thing happens in both dolphin and krusader. It looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/pO7KM.jpg]

I've found 7zips readme.txt in /usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/ and this is one of the things in it:

```
3) installing the context menu for KDE   (dolphin or konqueror)  
(tested on Ubuntu 10.10)
--------------------------------------------------
   for all:
   cp GUI/kde4/*.desktop /usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/
```

these are the 7zip files in that are located in that folder at the moment:

```
p7zip_compress2.desktop
p7zip_compress.desktop
p7zip_extract.desktop
p7zip_extract_subdir.desktop
p7zip_extract_to.desktop
p7zip_test.desktop
```

I guess some of them are extra but I am not sure which ones can be removed. 
I am using Arch with KDE and the packages are at the most recent versions. Did anyone else encounter this problem? Does anyone have an idea how to solve it so it would appear only once? I've been having this problem for a few months now (since I installed 7zip actually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and your question actually helped me out a lot. I tried to delete the first one (p7zip_compress2) after I checked that inside the file it had the same entries as the rest of the .desktop files... So delete it and solved! no need to restart or anything

Comment: sweet, thnx. I guess I was just to lazy to try it out, because I just thought it would be more complicated..